# Javascript and Django Rest Framework - cannot read property

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API endpoint that i created with Django Rest Framework. At first, my code worked but now i keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticker' of undefined
```

It's weird, because the `console.log`statement in the following  code returns nothing, although i'm sure that there is data in the endpoint that i'm calling.

This is what the data i'm trying to retrieve looks like:

```
[
 {
   ticker: "TEST",
   Price: 7876
 }
]
```

And this is the Ajax function that i built:

```
function doPoll(){

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/', function(data) {


        console.log(data[0]);

        $('#data').text(data[0].ticker + ' ' + data[0].Price);
        setTimeout(doPoll, 100);
    });
} 

doPoll();
```

And this is where the data should appear:

```
<h3 id="data"></h3>
```

The function should be supposed to place my data on my html page and refresh that data every second.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/` is the DRF API endpoint that i'm trying to call, from where i'm retrieving the JSON data.

Comment: what do your network logs show when requesting 127.0.0.1:8000/tst/? sounds like this is an issue in your backend, not front.

Comment: @bryan60 just checked, this is the response: {"count":1,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"ticker":"TEST","Price":7876}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access data.results... this is standard DRF response format

```
function doPoll(){

    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/', function(data) {

        var results = data.results;
        console.log(results[0]);

        $('#data').text(results[0].ticker + ' ' + results[0].price);
        setTimeout(doPoll, 100);
    });
} 

doPoll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here data[0].Price should be data[0].price

```
       $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/', function(data) {

             if(data && data.length > 0){
                console.log(data[0]);

                $('#data').text(data[0].ticker + ' ' + data[0].Price);
                setTimeout(doPoll, 100);
              }else{
                 //console.log('No Data')
                 console.log("DATA is: ", data)
              }

            });
```

Validate that data[0] exists before accessing properties of it

The best way to debug this is to check the response in your browser dev tools
Network tab

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo when editing the question. Corrected it right now

Comment: You should not get an error when you validate the data like this

Comment: It says 'no data', but i'm sure there is data, since Ajax is querying DRF, which takes the data from a Database

Comment: Try it with this second log in the else

Comment: still getting 'no data'

Comment: try it one more time pls

Comment: Still getting nothing!

Comment: There is a problem $.getJSON then, check ur dev tools for the response